# How to change Material UI tab button width

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way of changing the button's `min-width` property that's rendered inside a `<Tab />` in [Material UI](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/tabs)?

There doesn't seem to be a property that allows that or I cannot find it.

And since I'm new to React, I'm not quite sure what's the proper way of overriding the property.

Comment: Have you read through the [themes](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/themes/) documentation? In my experience, customizing Material UI components can be a gigantic pain because you can't always use inline styles.

Comment: I did. The tricky part is that the button is a child of the `<Tab/>`, so that's why I'm not sure that applying styling on the tab itself will fix anything. Because the actual `min-width` it's applied to the button which is a child of the tab.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've never used this library before, but according to the docs you can use the `classes` prop to add any custom styles.

In react we usually use the `className` property to add or overwrite styles for components, according to [the material-ui docs](https://material-ui-next.com/api/tab/), you can use `classes` which receives an object with the styles you need.

First you need to create the styles:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
  tabRoot: {
    minWidth: 10,
  },
});
```

The in the tab you use the `classes` prop like this:

```
<Tab label="X" classes={{ root: classes.tabRoot }} />
```

Here's an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/l52rw252rm

Comment: It looks like it works. I wasn't sure if applying the style on the tab was going to apply it to the child button. I'll give it a try later and let you know if it works.

Comment: According to the docs there are several classes you can overwrite. one of them is `root`, you also have a couple others for the `label`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use classes prop to apply width to Tab component.

```
const style = {
    root: {
     minWidth: 500
    }  
}

<Tab classes={style.root} />
```

Check [here](https://material-ui-next.com/api/tab/) for more details.

OR

You can also use inline-style like below

```
const style = {
   minWidth: 500
}

<Tab style={style} />
```

OR

If you feel inline-styles are lil difficult then customize your components using muitheme. check [here](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/themes/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can override it by using `withStyles` HOC.

```
const styles = {
 tab: {
  width: 140px
 }
}

export const MyTab = (props) => {
 return (
  <Tab className={props.classes.tab} label="Item One" />
 );
}

export default withStyles(styles)(MyTab);
```

Please check this doc regarding [overriding classes](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-classes)